# How to get list of api calls used in Application.apk?

Tags: android, apk

I have written a code which displays set of permissions used in the application.In the same way is there any way of getting all the API calls which is used in a application.I have 1000 apk file so manually not able to get the api calls so any body please help me .Thank you

NOTE: Manually getting the api calls by using the ApkAnalyser tool.

Comment: u try to get all apk which your mobile use  dude

Answer (score 0):

If you have got all the APK files, you can extract the classes.dex file. And you can write a program to create a DVM and load the classes. Then you can enumerate all the pacakges and classes in the apk, and you can reflect the class to get all the methods. Check if a specific method is Android API, by this way you can get the information you need.

Comment: No, you can simply extract if from APK file since APK is just ZIP package.

Comment: classes.dex is in unreadable format from that how will i extract api calls?

Comment: If you want to read dex file, you can use smali libraries. I am saying that you create Dalvik VM to load the dex classes. If you don't know what I am saying, you'd better to google Dalvik first.